# HTML Email Table data with equal height

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm currently working on a HTML template and Outlook has been a pain in the neck. I have a row with 2 td in which they have separate contents. Is there a supported way to set the height to be equal? Currently I have set a fixed height on the td but if I scale down to mobile version on Outlook. The text would wrap to the next line and cause the height to expand causing the 2 td to have different height.

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
        <h3>Content............</h3>
        <h3>Content.........</h3>
        <h3>Content........</h3>
        <h3>Content.......</h3>
   </td>
   <td>
        <h3>Content</h3>
        <h3>Content</h3>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

From the code above you can see that the first column would have a bigger height compared to the second column. How can I set the height to be equal without defining a specific height for it?. I have tried media queries however it is not supported on Outlook mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.....

```
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Footer</th>
      <th>Footer</th>
      <th>Footer</th>
      <th>Footer</th>
      <th>Footer</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Result</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Result</td>
      <td>Total Result</td>
      <td>Total Result</td>
      <td>Total Result</td>
      <td>Total Result</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I hope you find your answer.

Comment: As mentioned I don't want to define a fixed height to it. It should scale based on the column with the most content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged here because they don't explain how the code answers the question. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it solves the problem, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correct, then the two td's do have same height, you just want to align top content? The height is determined by the highest element in the . Its not possible to do width css and dynamic height. Either you set a fixed, or you let the heights height rull.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td valign="top">
    <h3>Content............</h3>
    <h3>Content.........</h3>
    <h3>Content........</h3>
    <h3>Content.......</h3>
   </td>
   <td valign="top">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <h3>Content</h3>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Bidstrup , Yes I'm aware the content would span based on the highest element in the row. However, whenever moving down to mobile version. The content would wrap to the next line forcing the height to expand. In that case, the neighboring elements wont expand.

Comment: @DexterSiah, So you want the height to stay the same in desktop and mobile view, even though it stacks the elements?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If the content within the two boxes ain't dynamic, you could just make some blank lines <h3>&nbsp;</h3> to keep the height the same